# Consumir SOAP desde vb

Tags: c#, visual-studio, vb

Tengo que consumir unos web services que son SOAP y manejan autenticación por token. Si lo implemento en `c#` puedo consumirlo correctamente, pero al implementarlo en `VB` no me funciona, el web service me dice que necesita autenticación, es como si no estuviera reconociendo el token que le envío.

Ambos proyectos estan usando la misma versión de framework, si me pudieran guiar en que me estoy equivocando se los agradeceria mucho, llevo varios días intentando detectar el error:

**Codigo en C#:**

```
    static void VerificarComunicacion()
      {

         string endpointAddress = "https://pilotosiatservicios.impuestos________?wsdl";
         string token = "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjg1MDUwMjFBYSIsIm9maWNpbmEiOiJINHNJQUFBQUFBQUFBRE1BQUNIZjJfUUJBQUFBIiwibml0IjoiSDRzSUFBQUFBQUFBQURNMHNqQTFNRFV3TWdRQTJ1aUJLUWtBQUFBPSIsImlkIjo0MjEyMzgsImV4cCI6MTYwOTA5NjA5MCwiaWF0IjoxNjA5MDgxNjMwLCJkZXBlbmRlbmNpYSI6Ikg0c0lBQUFBQUFBQUFETTBNQUFBNmxCM0l3TUFBQUE9In0.2Ym8Of4hg7Z7z3qz03CiRvGOo1PnkCuT89DcmEHx_HpwYrHRYPPg0InGRDj0WoiSNWP0Ks4TadJtFe-s9deF6A";

         BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding
         {
            SendTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1000),
            MaxBufferSize = int.MaxValue,
            MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue,
            AllowCookies = true,
            ReaderQuotas = XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas.Max
         };

         binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport; // https
                                                                  //binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.None; // http
         EndpointAddress address = new EndpointAddress(endpointAddress);
         ServicioFacturacionCodigosClient servicio = new ServicioFacturacionCodigosClient(binding, address);
         servicio.Endpoint.EndpointBehaviors.Add(new CustomAuthenticationBehaviour($"Token {token}"));
         try
         {
            Task<verificarComunicacionResponse> resp = servicio.verificarComunicacionAsync();
            resp.Wait();
            Console.WriteLine(resp.Result.@return);
         }
         catch (Exception e)
         {
            Console.WriteLine($"{e.Message}");
         }
      }
   }

 public class CustomAuthenticationBehaviour : IEndpointBehavior
   {
      readonly string _authToken;

      public CustomAuthenticationBehaviour(string authToken)
      {
         _authToken = authToken;
      }
      public void Validate(ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
      { }

      public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
      { }

      public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher)
      { }

      public void ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
      {
         clientRuntime.ClientMessageInspectors.Add(new CustomMessageInspector(_authToken));
      }
   }

   public class CustomMessageInspector : IClientMessageInspector
   {
      readonly string _authToken;

      public CustomMessageInspector(string authToken)
      {
         _authToken = authToken;
      }

      public object BeforeSendRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel)
      {
         var reqMsgProperty = new HttpRequestMessageProperty();
         reqMsgProperty.Headers.Add("Authorization", _authToken);
         request.Properties[HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name] = reqMsgProperty;
         return null;
      }

      public void AfterReceiveReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
      { }

   }
```

**Codigo de VB:**

```
Private Sub pruebaServicioToken()
      Try
         Dim token As String = "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjg1MDUwMjFBYSIsIm9maWNpbmEiOiJINHNJQUFBQUFBQUFBRE1BQUNIZjJfUUJBQUFBIiwibml0IjoiSDRzSUFBQUFBQUFBQURNMHNqQTFNRFV3TWdRQTJ1aUJLUWtBQUFBPSIsImlkIjo0MjEyMzgsImV4cCI6MTYwOTA5NjA5MCwiaWF0IjoxNjA5MDgxNjMwLCJkZXBlbmRlbmNpYSI6Ikg0c0lBQUFBQUFBQUFETTBNQUFBNmxCM0l3TUFBQUE9In0.2Ym8Of4hg7Z7z3qz03CiRvGOo1PnkCuT89DcmEHx_HpwYrHRYPPg0InGRDj0WoiSNWP0Ks4TadJtFe-s9deF6A"

         Dim binding As New System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding
         binding.SendTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1000)
         binding.MaxBufferSize = Integer.MaxValue
         binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = Integer.MaxValue
         binding.AllowCookies = True
         binding.ReaderQuotas = System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas.Max

         binding.Security.Mode = System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport

         Dim strURL As String = "https://pilotosiatservicios.impuestos________?wsdl"
         Dim address As New System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress(strURL)

         Dim servicio As New WS_Codigo.ServicioFacturacionCodigosClient(binding, address)
         servicio.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(New CustomAuthenticationBehaviour("Token " & token))
         Dim intRes = servicio.verificarComunicacion()
         If intRes = 926 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Comucacion Exitosa con SIN")
         Else
            MessageBox.Show("Errror de Comucacion con SIN (" & (intRes.ToString) & ")")
         End If
      Catch ex As Exception
         MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, Me.Text, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
      End Try
   End Sub


   Public Class CustomAuthenticationBehaviour
      Implements System.ServiceModel.Description.IEndpointBehavior

      Public _authToken As String  ''carlos: solo readonly

      Public Sub New(ByVal authToken As String)
         _authToken = authToken
      End Sub

      Public Sub Validate(endpoint As ServiceEndpoint) Implements IEndpointBehavior.Validate
         'Throw New NotImplementedException()
      End Sub

      Public Sub AddBindingParameters(endpoint As ServiceEndpoint, bindingParameters As ServiceModel.Channels.BindingParameterCollection) Implements IEndpointBehavior.AddBindingParameters
         'Throw New NotImplementedException()
      End Sub

      Public Sub ApplyDispatchBehavior(endpoint As ServiceEndpoint, endpointDispatcher As EndpointDispatcher) Implements IEndpointBehavior.ApplyDispatchBehavior
         'Throw New NotImplementedException()
      End Sub

      Public Sub ApplyClientBehavior(endpoint As ServiceEndpoint, clientRuntime As ClientRuntime) Implements IEndpointBehavior.ApplyClientBehavior
         clientRuntime.ClientMessageInspectors.Add(New CustomMessageInspector(_authToken))
      End Sub

   End Class

   Public Class CustomMessageInspector
      Implements System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.IClientMessageInspector

      Public _authToken As String

      Public Sub New(ByVal authToken As String)
         _authToken = authToken
      End Sub

      Public Sub AfterReceiveReply(ByRef reply As Channels.Message, correlationState As Object) Implements IClientMessageInspector.AfterReceiveReply
         'Throw New NotImplementedException()
      End Sub

      Public Function BeforeSendRequest(ByRef request As Channels.Message, channel As IClientChannel) As Object Implements IClientMessageInspector.BeforeSendRequest

         Dim reqMsgProperty As New System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpResponseMessageProperty()
         reqMsgProperty.Headers.Add("Authorization", _authToken)
         request.Properties(System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpResponseMessageProperty.Name) = reqMsgProperty
         Return Nothing

      End Function
   End Class
```

Comment: Estas consumiendolo en vb.net o vb6?

Comment: en este ejemplo esta en vb. net, pero al final quiero lograr consumirlo desde vb6

Comment: Y el codigo en vb6 que falla?

Comment: en ambas versiones de VB me arroja este mensaje, solo en c# funciona bien;

**"El servicio requiere autenticacion por TOKEN"**

Comment: Ok. Entonces centra tu pregunta en un problema a la vez. Ya que pusiste eñ codigo de vb.net, deja tu pregunta sobre eso. Saca el tag de vb6

Comment: ok, puse ambos VB porque en ambos me da el mismo problema, pero tienes razón tratare de funcione en uno a la vez.